# Read a list of another file in python

Tags: python, parsing

My text file named test.txt is like below.

```
[['A', 3.992303979497981], ['V', 2.2251878737397264], ['V', 2.703754348429766], ['A', 3.900215472550781], ['A', 4.99003388996634]
[['C', 3.5329528530441805], ['A', 1.1530906322097374], ['A', 2.666421771048816], ['V', 1.2859199105217558], ['B', 0.40879871489389696]
```

From another file code.py, How can I read the each line as a list with only values?
mean I want to get the values in a mylist like

```
mylist = [[[A],[V],[V],[A],[A]],
          [[C],[A],[A],[V],[B]]]
```

I tried doing below but It is not working.

```
import ast
with open('test.txt', 'r') as fp:
    mylisttrain = [ast.literal_eval(line) for line in fp]

price=[]
for x in range(0,2):
    for y in range(0,10):
        price.append([mylisttrain[x][y][0]])
```

It gives output like

```
[[A],[V],[V],[A],[A],
 [C],[A],[A],[V],[B]]
```

But, I want output like this.

```
[[[A],[V],[V],[A],[A]],
 [[C],[A],[A],[V],[B]]]
```

I want each line of input to be in a sub-list of its own.

Comment: Why aren't you using a pre-existing text-based serialization format like JSON instead of dumping the `str` representation of lists to a file?

Comment: Are you creating this file? If so, it's a bad idea to try to use `repr` (or `str`) and `literal_eval` as a data file format. Much better to use something like JSONLines, or one big JSON array.

Comment: It would be a great help if you can provide code because I do not have any idea about json.

Comment: To write a file: `with open('test.txt', 'w') as f: json.dump(mylisttrain, f)`. To read a file: `with open('test.txt') as f: mylisttrain = json.load(f)`. See the more detailed examples in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html), but really, that's all you need to get started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a nested list comprehension to retain the structure of the input:

```
import ast
new_s = [ast.literal_eval(line.strip('\n')+']') for line in open('filename.txt')]
final_data = [[[a] for a, _ in i] for i in new_s]
```

Output

```
[[['A'], ['V'], ['V'], ['A'], ['A']], [['C'], ['A'], ['A'], ['V'], ['B']]]
```

However, instead of a list comprehension, you can create a temporary list before your inner `for` loop to store the result of grabbing the first character:

```
price=[]
for i in mylisttrain:
   temp = []
   for a, _ in i:
     temp.append([a])
   price.append(temp)
```

Edit: to remove the brackets, you can use additional unpacking:

```
a, b = price
print(a)
print(b)
```

Output:

```
[['A'], ['V'], ['V'], ['A'], ['A']]
[['C'], ['A'], ['A'], ['V'], ['B']]
```

Comment: That's a really hacky—and fragile—idea. (I suppose if the first bug convinces the OP to stop using `repr` as a persistence format, that might be a good thing…)

Comment: It says invalid syntax

Comment: @ViralPatel Can you specify where the error is occurring?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp.py", line 2, in <module>
    new_s = [ast.literal_eval(line+']') for line in open('test.txt')]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ast.py", line 49, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ast.py", line 37, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 2
    ]
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @ViralPatel If the first solution with the list comprehension does not work for you, I added another possibility that merely tweaks your current code.

Comment: @abarnert I do agree that there is no clean way to parse the file as it currently stands, however, I did add a solution that will correct the code that the OP has currently written.

Comment: Thanks It is working but what if I want to get the second values. Like what if my array is like [[[A,1],[V,2],[V,3],[A,4],[A,5]],
          [[C,6],[A,7],[A,8],[V,9],[B,10]]] and I want to get the values as [[[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]],[[6],[7],[8],[9],[10]]]

Comment: @ViralPatel simply change the order of the unpacking. For instance, in the second `for` loop, the header becomes: `for _, a in i:`, and the loop block remains the same.

Comment: As in the given question the values are in float. What if I want to get those values the same way as I get the Alphabets?

Comment: Hi ... Is there any way to remove first and last square bracket?
[[['A'], ['V'], ['V'], ['A'], ['A']], [['C'], ['A'], ['A'], ['V'], ['B']]] in this?

Comment: @ViralPatel What is your desired output after removing the brackets?

Comment: [['A'], ['V'], ['V'], ['A'], ['A']], [['C'], ['A'], ['A'], ['V'], ['B']] this is desired. But, I don;t want to convert it to string and show. I need this updated list in next function.